# Safari 6+ won't scroll Iframe on first load

Tags: html, css, iframe, safari

I have an Iframe that displays content when the user scrolls with the mousewheel.
Everything works as expected in all major browsers but on Safari the Iframe wont let me scroll via mousewheel.

**However** it does work after a reload of the page and after that it works pretty much every time

Here is the Link: http://bit.ly/1uwBCqV

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If anyone ever has the same problem, this fixed it for me.

Put an empty onmousewheel attribute on your iframe HTML element. Seems to be a bug in Safari 6+